# Eclipse 2022-09: Maven update failure

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

Upgraded my eclipse to 2022-09 few days ago. I am getting the below error when i do a maven update on a project.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.ProjectConfigurationRequest.getProject()'
>        at org.jboss.tools.maven.jdt.configurators.EndorsedLibProjectConfigurator.configureRawClasspath(EndorsedLibProjectConfigurator.java:113)
> :

Platform:

1. Windows 10
2. Java 1.8
3. JBoss Tools 4.24.0.Final
4. Maven Profiles Management 1.5.5
5. m2e-apt 1.5.4
6. Hibernate Tools (Helios) 3.4.x

Any help would be great.
Thx

Comment: Which m2e version?

Comment: @howlger How do i find out? i am not sure if these are the one. I see m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.5.2.20220906-1452 and M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse 2.0.4.20220904-1703. There are other m2e e.g. m2e-wtp - JSF etc but think they are not related. This error seems related to JBoss Maven Tool calling m2e core (??)

Comment: Yes, looks like a JBoss Tools issue caused by the m2e update from 1.x to 2.0.4. m2e-apt became part of m2e. If you have m2e-apt from JBoss, uninstall it. I guess there will be a new JBoss Tools release in about two weeks which hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: @howlger Tx. I'll try .. appreciate much.

Comment: This is due to [`ProjectConfigurationRequest`](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/project/configurator/ProjectConfigurationRequest.java) being refactored into a record.

Comment: I also have this problem. I don't have m2e-apt.  I uninstalled m2e-wtp as described in the accepted answer, but that didn't work for me, either. I am stuck with 2022-06 until this whole thing gets resolved.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr If it's not m2e-apt, something else still uses the method that was first deprecated and then removed in 2022-09. Maybe the stack trace can give you a hint which plugin is causing it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this reminds me of earlier conversations.  It's the groovy-eclipse integration. I'll ping them again for the status on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is due to a breaking-change M2E version upgrade.

I had to uninstall these two highlighted to get it to work:

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me. I never did find the second component, "JDT APT", but I now have nothing with "m2e-wtp", but I still get the same error as described in the OP when I do a Maven Update.

Comment: how can I access this tap?

Answer (score 3):

It's already in the comments of the question, but I'll put it as an answer, so that it's easily visible:
You might have to uninstall m2e-apt, because it became part of the m2e core packages in 2.x.

> m2e-apt functionality is now directly included in m2e 2.x, therefore this m2e-apt entry is no longer compatible with Eclipse 2022-09 and needs to be removed.

See here:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and reinstalled **m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP** and I could update the maven project again with no issues
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hEcb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had no «Maven Eclipse JDT APT» component installed and «m2e-wtp» uninstall/reinstall did not work for me either.
Eventually I removed all «Spring *» components via Help↦About↦Installation Details. That fixed Maven Update. Then I installed Spring Suite 4 from marketplace. Now Maven Update works fine from Eclipse 2023-06 (4.28.0) with Spring Suite 4 as well. Spent few very exciting days figuring it out) ♡ Eclipse no matter what