# NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.ResolverConfiguration.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String)' java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExe

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

facing this issue while creating spring starter project in eclipse IDE, i have installed STS plugins also
I tried of installing latest version of eclipse also

Comment: Missing dependency

Comment: The current m2e (maven support) ResolverConfiguration class doesn't seem to have a setActiveProfiles method. Possibly the STS plugins need an older version (or need to be updated)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Something is using a [deprecated API of m2e (the Maven integration of Eclipse) that has been removed in the current version of m2e](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/commit/cab8936dec18386354d6fc9e431e82f26197cb7d). It is not clear from the cropped message what this something is. Are you sure everything is up to date (_Help > Check for Updates_)? Please show the full error message starting with `!SESSION` (see _Error Log_ view, select the error, copy it and paste it as text to your question).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/73757713/6505250 including the comments (as it is unclear what exactly is using the method that has been removed).