# Problem creating a new spring boot project in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

When I click on the "create new spring starter project" button I follow the steps and everything works normally but when I finish it I get the following error

Click to view

[image: 1]

In text its following error:
NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.ResolverConfiguration.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String)'
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

When I check the eclipse-workspace folder I get the projects created but I can't open them in eclipse

Comment: A plugin seems to be outdated, calling a method of the Maven integration (m2e) that no longer exists. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757713/eclipse-2022-09-maven-update-failure#comment131909489_73757713 Unfortunately your question does not contain the full error details (in the _Error Log_ view select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste the text into your question) and does also not say which m2e version you have and which plugins you have installed.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error when creating a new spring project in Eclipse.
***NoSuchMethodError***, when creating a new Spring project in Eclipse can be caused by various factors, including compatibility issues between different versions of libraries or plugins.
**Installing the new Eclipse version worked for me**. Using the latest version of Eclipse ensures that I have access to the most up-to-date features, bug fixes, and compatibility improvements.